# renv: install R packages without help pages & Co

Tags: r, renv

With R's `install.packages()`, it is possible to exclude certain parts of a package, which are only helpful during development - such as help pages and example data - to yield lightweight runtime environments (e.g. smaller Docker images):

```
install.packages('data.table',
                 INSTALL_opts = c('--no-docs', '--no-help', '--no-html', '--no-data'))
```

Now, I am wondering, if such a feature exists also for `renv` (and I was just too blind to find it on the web)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://rstudio.github.io/renv/reference/install.html#package-configuration:

> Similarly, additional flags that should be passed to R CMD INSTALL can
> be set via the install.opts R option:
>
> ```
> # installation of R packages using the Windows Subsystem for Linux
> # may require the `--no-lock` flag to be set during install
> options(install.opts = "--no-lock")
> renv::install("xml2")
> ```

You can also use the package name in the option, e.g.

```
options(install.opts = list(xml2 = <...>))
```

if you wanted package-specific installation options; e.g. you wanted to exclude vignettes for certain packages.